# How to join textures without them merging into one?

Tags: texturing

I was following a tutorial on making a tree. When the guy pressed CTR + J, all his textures were still separate. However, when I try to do the same thing, this happens:[image: the leaves all combine into one big texture spread across the branch]

How do I group them so that the textures dont combine?

Comment: Can you please attach the link of the tutorial, and the blend file? It would be hard to investigate without those resources.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQUO9yL2vYQ at 48:36 in the video Im not sure how to add a blend file

Comment: Did you have any modifiers on the meshes you joined?  Applying the modifiers before joining might fix it.